# HDF5: Parallel reading and writing different files

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, hdf5

It seems that HDF5 serializes all API calls. It even seems this happens if I read one HDF5-file in thread1 and writing another HDF5-files in thread2.

I guess it is defined here:
https://github.com/qsnake/hdf5/blob/4d8cf3bdf160984cc06fceec497d7d160dfbcfb3/src/H5private.h#L1787

Can this somehow be avoided? I have an application which reads one huge HDF5-file and writes another one. So I really prefer it to read and write in parallel (and using queueing in between).

I use the C-API of HDF5 and the library I use is compiled with the "thread-safe"-option (which just seems to add this global lock).

Thanks

Comment: The documentation does have this info on [Parallel HDF5](https://portal.hdfgroup.org/display/HDF5/Parallel+HDF5) if that helps at all.

Comment: Thanks, that is really a good starting point. I did not yet get it working, but it can't be that hard:)

Comment: Parallel HDF5 seems mostly to be used to write from multiple processes to the same file, but I try to do the opposite (1 process, many files). I guess it also should work, but unfortunately I could not just "copy-paste-modify" an example.